# why link title not showing in IE but showing in firefox?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, xhtml

see example here http://jsbin.com/elesa

code

```
 <p>
  <a target="_blank" href="#" title="Download PDF, 58KB, opens in a new window">
  <img width="150" height="50" border="0" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" alt=""/>
  </a>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers give presedence to the `title` and the `alt` differently.  The safest method to achieve the proper results is to supply the same title on both the `title` and the `alt` tag of the image.  For example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="#" title="Download PDF, 58KB, opens in a new window">
  <img width="150" height="50" border="0" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" 
       alt="Download PDF, 58KB, opens in a new window"/>
</a>
```

Comment: oh - now need to change in 60 images :(